# What extra circuitry is recommended for a plain micro SD card adapter

Tags: sd, solid-state-devices

I intend to use an SD card to record the movement (X,Y,C) of an animal for a research purpose.

I am using the Texas Instruments ARM Cortex-M4 TM4C123GH6PM launchpad along with a Sparkfun Micro-SD card adapter. I use SPI protocol to write/read the micro SD card.

[image]

Above is a photo of the specific micro SD adapter I use.  Please note this is a type of adapter that has no resistors, capacitors attached to any pin on it.

I want to ensure reliability of my application as it is of imperative importance. If the SD gets corrupted within 14 days after mounting, more funds will have to be spent re-collaring the animal.

I have tried my best to ensure software reliability but I sometimes get errors when I use fprintf, fsync upon which I re-initialize and arrange the file for appending again. At last, if nothing works I RESET the system fully. A reset usually mounts the filesystem again and usually works. But that is something I don't want to do.

I write ten of following strings a second and that is all I write to data.txt

1014067x3.97y-1.82z8.31x-0.02y-0.02z-0.01T5-45-28-900GPGLL,0654.8824,N,07958.3790,E,171619.300,AB88,4030

I have connected this micro SD adapter directly to the MCU SPI pins. There are no resistors, capacitors as support circuity. i had this micro SD adapter with pull-up resistors etc and I have already noted better reliability with that adapter. But I want to know for sure if additional circuitry can help.

Would someone be able to help me know if pull-ups or any additional circuitry would make my SD writes more reliable?

At the moment I have noted I receive about 1-2 errors from one of the Fat-fs functions I use every 3-6 hours. The system must run for 14 days and the data.txt is expected t become as big as 1.5GB after 14 days.

Comment: What speed are you running the SPI bus?

Answer (score 1):

Well from an electrical standpoint, you probably want series termination resistors like 22 ohm close the the SD card, you may require pullups on the data and clk lines depending on the microcontroller. Also a 0.1uF cap from Vcc to Gnd very close the the SD card.
But that single 1G file is a huge risk. If you can make it smaller that is much better. I'm not 100% sure but the SD card may need to rewrite the whole file every time. That will burn up the write cycles on the card as well as make it error prone.

Comment: would you please tell me what you mean by being unsure if SD cards requires to re write the file everytime?

Comment: I am reasonably certain that SD only needs blocks updated, not the whole file. However, I agree, writing everything into one file seems suboptimal.

Comment: I think this is what the f_sync command does. I do not close and open file. I fprintf and use f_sync.  It flushes the content to the file and I dont have to close and re open the file before the next write. Breaking the file into multiple ones can be really difficult  as naming can get complex. This is because I RESET system at an error. any advices? I have a GPS, and an accelerometer running.

Comment: Doyou think I had those resets because my resistors and capasitor was missing? Thank you very much for this kind information. I will try the new things you mentions. Pls advice more if you think anything may be usefull for me to ensure reliability

Answer (score 0):

You should have a capacitor, close to the socket. across the SD adapters power pins, and resistors to improve signal quality on data lines.

Instead of one big file, I would be very tempted to create many new files, maybe every hour or less.

One concern would be updating the file's 'meta data' blocks. The SD card's file system also uses blocks to record which blocks the file is using, how big the file is, etc. Those blocks should be updated on every flush. So they will get rewritten frequently. They may be more of an issue than the data blocks themselves which likely only get updated a couple of times, ever.

Updating those meta-data blocks continuously might 'wear' quite a lot of blocks. The SD card's internal firmware tries to 'level' wear on blocks. When that firmware decides a block may be close to failure, it will copy the contents of the block to a new block, and remove that worn block from further use.

Conversely, not updating that meta-data at all would be bad, as any glitch may cause the file to be damaged and hard to recover because their would be no permanent record on disk of which blocks are used (a file recovery program might be able to make good guesses though).

Creating lots of files might increase the chances of having recoverable data, while spreading the 'wear' on 'meta-data' blocks and so give better overall wear.

Use simple file names like 'f000000', then 'f000001'. Your software should be able to read the directory, find the most recent name, and carry on with the next file name in the sequence. When you recover the data, amalgamating it all into one file should be easy, for example *NIX `cat` will do that.